# symfony kernel.request event listener disable transaction

Tags: symfony

I want log route visited info, so I insert a mysql record.
This is my event listener.

```
   /**
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
       $request = $event->getRequest();

       // Matched route
       $_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');
       $post = $request->request->all();
       $get = $request->query->all();
       
       $menu = $doctrine->getRepository('SystemBundle:Menu')->findOneBy([
           'englishName' => $_route
       ]);
       if(empty($menu)){
           $routeName = '未知路由';
       }else{
           $routeName = $menu->getName();
       }
       $systemLog = new SystemLog();
       $systemLog->setAdminId($userId);
       $systemLog->setUsername($username);
       $systemLog->setRoute($_route);
       $systemLog->setRouteName($routeName);
       $systemLog->setUri($request->getUri());
       $systemLog->setGetParameter(json_encode($get));
       $systemLog->setPostParameter(json_encode($post));
       $systemLog->setIp($request->getClientIp());
       $systemLog->setCreateAt(new \DateTime());
       $em->persist($systemLog);
       $em->flush();
    }
```

When I debug doctrine:
[debug bar shortcut img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj0TX.jpg)

It wastes me a lot of time.
(symfony 3.4.11)
How can I disable transaction?

Comment: transaction commit about 16ms, like as "debug bar shortcut img" display

Comment: 20ms - a lot of time? I'm not sure if this is really that bad. Unless you expect large-scale traffic I wouldn't worry about it. Addendum: and MySQL has to do some transaction anyway, so you can't get rid of it.

Comment: @vstm thx, I'm optimizing my API, and in this scenario, I don't need to start transaction, so I want to close it, rather than all API  cost extra 16ms.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for doctrine [auto_commit](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.7/reference/transactions.html#auto-commit-mode)? But doesn't it make more sense to do this in log files?

Comment: Well the transaction is going to happen even if you don't explicitly create it - at some point you have to wait for MySQL to do it's thing. The only thing that would make it faster is to switch the storrage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM, since MyISAM doesn't do transactions and thus [has a better performance when `INSERT`ing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16395/mysql-insert-performance-innodb-vs-myisam).